# Can't able to upgrade command "apt upgrade"

Tags: upgrade, systemd, udev

[image]

If I try to install those dependencies it shows

[image]

Force install shows following error: `sudo apt install -f`

```
(Reading database ... 92 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.18) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/bin/journalctl.dpkg-new' (while processing './bin/journalctl'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS & **most importantly** release details (*deb* packages are built for a specific release) so are we to guess?  Providing text (*instead of picture*) allows us to copy & paste details into a browser (*or CLI which is my preference*) for enquiries, so given you have access to the text & know the release - it's easier if you explore yourself (*instead of us needing to guess required details such as release*).  I'd also return to basics; ie. knowing your release, I'd likely `sudo apt update` & read the output ensuring no warnings, missing lines etc were ignored...

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 and 

root@appserver-digitaldash:~# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:4 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 3s (114 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
21 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: and when I try to upgrade


https://prnt.sc/6odfJqJW_EUk

Comment: apt --fix-broken install 
command output: https://prnt.sc/svHVUO8SrAfN

Comment: Is this a WSL or some other kind of virtualized system? Most of the issues look like hardware-related packages. The lack of systemd is also a clue. And why are you using `sudo` at a root prompt?

Comment: Does it make any difference, actually I don't know that much about it. I thought it would be ignored if it is sudo for root user. BTW If you could help me to solve my issue, that would be greatly appreciated.